# data-rel="external" not working in jQueryMobile Beta 2 and PhoneGap 1.0

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I just upgraded to PhoneGap 1.0 and jQueryMobile Beta 2 and it seems like file:// navigation is totally borked.  I've posted a super stripped-down 2 page example for Android 2.2 here: https://bitbucket.org/uhlenhuthm/pgdemo/overview

DETAILED PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:

I've created a very simple 2 page test application in PhoneGap 1.0 for Android.  In my assets/www folder, I have two files: index.html and hola.html.  PhoneGap loads the index.html file which contains a single button (see below).  Clicking on the button SHOULD load a new page (no AJAX loading), but instead the button just changes color while being tapped and nothing else happens.  This only happens when the link has data-ajax="false".  Setting data-rel="external" actually has no effect and JQM loads the page using AJAX (another bug).  AJAX loading works fine, but that's not what I need (for a more complex project).  Including the phonegap.min.js file doesn't fix the problem either.

The weird thing is that this works in the browser (not going through PhoneGap on the phone, it goes to hola.html no problem).  Maybe there's something weird with how JQM and PhoneGap deal with file:// URLs?

Am I making a bonehead mistake or is there something really wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempt to give [this](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/07/upgrading-your-phonegap-android.html) a read. He points out many different issues with upgrades, this being one of them. Here is a quote detailing what probably is causing this issue: "If you are unable to open a second html page in your app then you're missing the following tag which should be placed in the application tag of your apps AndroidManifest.xml:"

```
<activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"><intent-filter></intent-filter></activity>
```

I hope this helps!